# Bash colon operator in variable substitution?

Tags: string, bash, variables, variable-substitution

I inherited some bash code and these two lines are bewildering me:

```
branch_name=`git describe --contains --all HEAD`
branch_name=${branch_name:-HEAD}
```

My understanding of the `:` colon operator is that is creates a substring based on an index so using a string, `-HEAD` in this case, does not make any sense.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This takes the variable `branch_name`, if it is defined. If it is not defined, use `HEAD` instead.

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for details:

> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion
>
> The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion. ...
>   The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}.
>   ...
>   When not performing substring expansion, using the form described below (e.g., ‘:-’), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.
>
> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

---

Substrings are covered a few lines below. The difference between the two is

```
${parameter:-word}
```

vs

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}
```

> **${parameter:offset}**
>   **${parameter:offset:length}**
>
> This is referred to as Substring Expansion. It expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.
>   ...
>   If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter. ... *Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused with the ‘:-’ expansion.*

Comment: And what if there is only ':-' ? LIke "${RDAUTH:-}"

Comment: This works like an empty string, tt gives either the contents of `RDAUTH` or an empty string.

Answer (score 26):

In this case, the colon is just a modifier for the `-` operator. `${branch-HEAD}` would expand to "HEAD" only if `branch` is unset, while `${branch:-HEAD}` expands to "HEAD" if `branch` is the null string as well.

```
$ branch=master
$ echo "${branch-HEAD} + ${branch:-HEAD}"
master + master
$ branch=""
$ echo "${branch-HEAD} + ${branch:-HEAD}"
 + HEAD
$ unset branch
$ echo "${branch-HEAD} + ${branch:-HEAD}"
HEAD + HEAD
```

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

Answer (score 7):

In bash, `${VAR1:-VAR2}` is equivalent to SQL's `coalesce(VAR1, VAR2)`, or C#'s `VAR1 ?? VAR2`.

In your case:

```
branch_name=`git describe --contains --all HEAD`
branch_name=${branch_name:-HEAD}
```

The first line executes the `git` command and sets the value in the `branch_name` variable, then, the second line coalesces its value assigning the value of `HEAD` if `branch_name` is null.

As you said `${VAR1:NUM}` is a string prefix operation (`left` in SQL), which when used with a negative number, as `${VAR1: -NUMBER}` becomes a suffix (`right`) operation. Note the whitespace before the minus sign: if you skip that whitespace it becomes the `coalesce` operation as I've said before.