# Bash Code, what does this do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This may sound like a very simple question, but what does

```
ADB=${ADB:-adb}
```

do?

I've run it and it sets `$ADB` to `adb` , I know the assignment of the value to the `ADB` shell variable part, but what does `${ADB:-adb}` do? I haven't seen this syntax/usage before.

Comment: It was recently commented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143863/bash-colon-operator

Comment: if the variable `ADB` is not set, then it gets set to `adb`, otherwise it keeps it's old value. This is explained in various FAQs and in the bash manual page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ADB` variable is not set, `bash` will displays the string `adb`.

Another trick is to type :

```
echo ${ADB:=adb}
```

In this case, `ADB` variable is assigned with the string `adb` (still if `ADB` is not set)

All of these nice features are [bash *parameter expansions*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: A shorter alternative to that trick is `: ${ADB:=adb}`; you don't have to assign the value twice.

Comment: post edited accordingly, thanks, typed too fast